# Django - Unit Tests on localhost creating objects in main database, but not finding them in the test database later in the method

Tags: python, django

Experiencing some fairly strange behaviour with django unit tests. I have a class inherited from django.test.testcase that verifies a registration form creates a person object and a user object, which it does, but I can subsequently look for and find the objects in the Admin interface after the tests have finished. This is the test:

```
import unittest
import time
from django.test import TestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from apps.persons.models import Person

class NewVisitorTest(TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

def tearDown(self):
    self.browser.quit()

def test_can_sign_up_and_login(self):

    # User goes to register url
    self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/register/')

    # User can see that she has come to the right page on the website
    self.assertIn('Register', self.browser.title)

    # User can see that there is a sign up form
    signup_form = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_registration_form')

    # User can enter text into the first name field
    first_name_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_first_name')
    first_name_input.send_keys('Jim')

    # User can enter text into the last name field
    last_name_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_last_name')
    last_name_input.send_keys('bob')

    # User can enter text into the username field
    username_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_username')
    username_input.send_keys('jim_bob')

    # User can enter text into the email field
    email_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_email')
    email_input.send_keys('jim_bob@jimbob.com')

    # User can enter text into the first password field
    password_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_password')
    password_input.send_keys('kittensarecute')

    # User can enter text into the second password field
    password_1_input = self.browser.find_element_by_id('id_password1')
    password_1_input.send_keys('kittensarecute')

    # Submit form
    signup_form.submit()

    time.sleep(20)


    persons = Person.objects.all()
    print persons
    self.assertEqual(len(persons), 1)

    users = User.objects.all()
    print users
    self.assertEqual(len(users), 1)

    # Deliberately fail
    self.fail('Finish the test!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The code fails on assertEqual(len(persons), 1). I can reproduce the same behaviour in the browser and have no issues. Each time I run the test I have to delete the user it creates in the main local database, so I'm assuming it's saving the objects in the database defined in settings['databases'], but then looking for them in the test database later in the method. I see in the terminal that the test database is created at the beginning of each test, so it's definitely there, which seems confusing. Any help would be massively appreciated.

EDIT: It's all on sqlite

```
 File ".../tests/tests.py", line 60, in test_can_sign_up_and_login
    self.assertEqual(len(persons), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

Edit 2:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '/Users/me/github/stage/project/data/db.db', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}
```

I have a folder with apps in them, so to run these tests and run:

```
python manage.py test tests
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback please?

Comment: @CarlosV Ah, yes I just included it.

Comment: Can you please post the LiveServerTestCase version together with db settings and how do you run test in cmd.

Comment: ok you still didn't post the LiveServerTestCase class version of your test, so I don't know what exactly are you doing wrong, my last guess is to use self.live_server_url as url instead of fixed url.

Comment: @mariodev It was exactly the same output.

Comment: @Ergusto I did a fast example test with LiveServer and it works properly, maybe you could upload your project files somewhere, so I can take a look.

Answer (score 7):

You're right, django creates a test database inside your tests. From the docs:

> Tests that require a database (namely, model tests) will not use your
>   “real” (production) database. Separate, blank databases are created
>   for the tests.
>   [full documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database)

Which is the correct thing to do. Unit test should be isolated from one another in order to avoid a dirty environment (a previous test forgets to remove a record/file/object it created and it affects the result of the other tests).

---

What you are doing is called [Functional Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_testing). You are testing that your web application form submits, validates, saves, etc all in one test. Since the act of doing this implicates that many pieces of code run, it's not considered *unit* testing. When you perform these types of tests, your assertions should also be similar:

- assert thank you/welcome message is shown
- go to the user management page and assert new person is there
- check that they can log it
- etc

This tests that your application functions correctly.

The difference between the two types of testing is that Functional Testing tests *what* your application is doing, whereas Unit Testing tests *how* it's doing it.

This is crucial because you could be saving your data in a number of ways:

- As JSON into a file
- As XML
- In a database locally
- In the cloud somewhere

Your functional test doesn't really care *how* this is done, it just cares that when you go to a specific page, it gets the data. But unit test will drastically change depending on which way you're using.

---

In your case, you are using both ways of testing. Selenium (opening a page, filling it out, submitting it) is testing *what* the application does (functional), but your assertions (was the data was saved to the database) is testing *how* you store the data (unit).

So I suggest that you change your assertions to fit the rest of your test. And move the current ones into your unit tests:

```
def test_user_is_save(self):
   addUser(...)
   users = User.objects.all()
   self.assertEqual(len(users), 1)
```

This will test that your `addUser` method is working correctly (saving to the db), which is what *unit* test is about. And your current test will test that when you submit the form, the user sees the right thing.

Comment: I am already testing creating the object using the django api in other tests. This is, as you say, a functional test. You might infer that from observing that the name of the method is 'NewVisitorTest.test_can_sign_up_and_login' The explanation was appreciated but unnecessary.

Comment: @Ergusto I saw that, however since your test is not 100% functional (it just tests the person was created in the db vs the user can log in), I wasn't sure if you were fully aware of the differences. Hence the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LiveServerTestCase` instead and access to your service with 
`self.live_server_url`.

You will be able to get objects from the test database models normally with `Entry.objects.get`

```
import requests
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class FunctionalTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def test_get_comments(self):
        response = requests.get(f"{self.live_server_url}/api/comments/?page=1")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LiveServerTestCase, so that django can run it's own test server and therefore use it's own test db.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#live-test-server

Comment: Exact same result. Traceback:
'
self.assertEqual(len(persons), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
'

Comment: @Ergusto Just a tip, and it will improve your unittest. Never have more than 1 assert statement per unit test. Because if one assert fails then the rest of your test will fail as well. Breaking it down into smaller pieces will allow you to be clearer as well and it's more maintainable. Also making it deliberately fail when done is bad on so many levels.

Comment: @limelights I'm aware of that. This is a copy of the original file. This function mostly turned into a debugging exercise. This isn't how it was set out at first. I even tried submitting the form on setup, same behaviour.